# Sass giving Error Ionic serve Compile Failed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, node-sass

I’m having isues with ionic cordova run android -l
everything was working good. I’ve updated my nodejs on pc. Now i’m having isues with build.

```
[app-scripts] [10:41:36]  sass started ... 
[app-scripts] [10:41:37]  sass: src/theme/variables.scss, line: 36 
[app-scripts]             (skyblue: #488aff, primaryText: #727270, headers: #5e5e5e, secondary: #32db64, danger: #ca2929, light: 
[app-scripts]             #f4f4f4, dark: #222, orange: #fc6108, sos: #7a08fc, blu: #3e6aca, gray: #7e7e7e, activeBg: #dadedf, 
[app-scripts]             disabled: (contrast: #aaaaaa, base: #e7e7e7), green: (contrast: #fafafa, base: #2ecc71), primary: (contrast: 
[app-scripts]             #f4f4f4, base: #727270), primary-menu: (contrast: #33cfff, base: #f4f4f4), redIcons: (contrast: #ca2929, 
[app-scripts]             base: #f4f4f4)) isn't a valid CSS value. 
[app-scripts]       L36:  $colors:(
[app-scripts]       L37:    skyblue:    #488aff,

[INFO] Development server running!
```

IONIC INFO

```
Ionic CLI : 5.4.1 (/Users/pc-areaindustries/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ionic) Ionic Framework : 
ionic-angular 3.9.8 @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4 Cordova: Cordova CLI : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1) 
Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4 Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, 
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.0, (and 20 other plugins) Utility: cordova-res : 0.6.0 native-run : 0.2.7 (update available: 0.2.8) 
System: Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/pc-areaindustries/Library/Android/sdk) 
ios-deploy : 1.9.4 ios-sim : 7.0.0 NodeJS : v10.16.0 (/usr/local/bin/node) npm : 6.11.3 OS : macOS Mojave Xcode : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Inside Variable.scss i have this var

```
$colors:(
skyblue:    #488aff,
primaryText:#727270,
headers:    #5e5e5e,
secondary:  #32db64,
danger:     #ca2929,
light:      #f4f4f4,
dark:       #222,
orange:     #fc6108,
sos:        #7a08fc,
blu:        #3e6aca,
gray:       #7e7e7e,
activeBg:  #dadedf,
disabled: (
contrast: #aaaaaa,
base: #e7e7e7
),
green:   (
contrast: rgb(250, 250, 250),  /* color */
base: #2ecc71 /* background */
),
primary: (
contrast: #f4f4f4,
base: #727270
),
// side menu color
primary-menu: (
contrast: #33cfff,
base: #f4f4f4
),
redIcons: (
contrast: #ca2929,
base: #f4f4f4
),
);
```

does anyone have the solution? already did this:

```
removed “node_modules” then npm install
npm update
npm rebuild node-sass
```

etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was in the variable names. So i solved it by fixing the name.